# How to refresh the first page with TabBarViews when I pop from the second page?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tabbar

I have one page as the first page with TabbarViews, the TabbarViews show some datas which were got form website, so when I finish sent some datas in the second page, the datas in TabbarViews also change. I need to get new datas in TabbarViews. The first page looks like,

```
import 'firstFloorView.dart';

class FirstFloorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String number;
  const FirstFloorPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.number,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstFloorPageState createState() => _FirstFloorPageState();
}

class _FirstFloorPageState extends State<FirstFloorPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  /// tabbar
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
    _tabController.addListener(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("First page"),
        actions: [
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Go to Second Page"),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "view1",),
                      Tab(text: "view2",),
                    ],
                    controller: _tabController,
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(color: Colors.grey,height: 0,thickness: 1,),
                Expanded(child: TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: [
                    FloorView(str:"1"),
                    FloorView(str:"2"),
                  ],
                ),)
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

And my TabbarView is this:

```
class FloorView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FloorView({
    Key? key,
    required this.str
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String str;

  @override
  _FloorViewState createState() => _FloorViewState();
}

class _FloorViewState extends State<FloorView> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print(widget.str);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("${widget.str}"),
    );
  }
}
```

The second page is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Pop back to First Page"),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to refresh all datas of first page(with all datas in Tabbarviews) when I pop from the second page. How to make it? Maybe, I need to rebuild the first page?

Answer (score 0):

You can await the navigation and set state like this

```dart
onPressed: ()async{
          await Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
                ),
              );
       setState((){});
      }
```

**EDIT**

I have created a demo to show its working

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: Page1());
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  String helloText = "Hellow world";
  Color bgColor = Colors.white;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(helloText),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2()));
              helloText = "hello Text Updated";
              bgColor = Colors.yellow;
              setState(() {});
            },
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text("Navigate to page2"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text("Close pop up"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: No,it doesn't work. When I pop, the Tabbarviews have no change.

Comment: please Try by updating some value in page 1 before you set state.

Comment: Edited my answer with a working demo

Comment: I tried your answer but my pages are too complex, it just partly works in some situations. That makes me dispirited, but still thank you, guy! I am trying to find other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a State Management package like [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to share state between multiple pages.

Taking your code as an example, I've changed it to include the `provider` package and share state between 1st and 2nd pages. On the 2nd page, you roll 2 dices. Then, on the 1st page, the data is updated with the values you get from the dices.

This is done by creating a model that extends [`ChangeNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html). This model is where the state is and whenever the model state changes the [`notifyListeners()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/notifyListeners.html) should be called such that other pages update/rebuild themselves.

To consume the model state use the [`Consumer`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html) widget and to make the model available to the app to be consumed use the [`Provider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider-class.html) or the [`MultiProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html).

Here's [the official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) on the `provider` package.

Check the code and also the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=121e69b230af1d4380b050e4d04e6920):

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Model())],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const FirstFloorPage(number: '1234'),
    );
  }
}

class FirstFloorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String number;
  const FirstFloorPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.number,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstFloorPage> createState() => _FirstFloorPageState();
}

class _FirstFloorPageState extends State<FirstFloorPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  /// tabbar
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
    _tabController.addListener(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('First page'),
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Go to Second Page'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const SecondPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TabBar(
              tabs: const [
                Tab(text: 'view1'),
                Tab(text: 'view2'),
              ],
              controller: _tabController,
            ),
            const Divider(
              color: Colors.grey,
              height: 0,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Consumer<Model>(builder: (context, model, _) {
                return TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: [
                    FloorView(str: 'Dice 1 = ${model.dice1 ?? 'Roll first'}'),
                    FloorView(str: 'Dice 2 = ${model.dice2 ?? 'Roll first'}'),
                  ],
                );
              }),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class FloorView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FloorView({Key? key, required this.str}) : super(key: key);
  final String str;

  @override
  State<FloorView> createState() => _FloorViewState();
}

class _FloorViewState extends State<FloorView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(widget.str),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Consumer<Model>(builder: (context, model, child) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Roll dices'),
                onPressed: () {
                  model.roll();
                },
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text('Dice 1 = ${model.dice1 ?? 'Roll first'}'),
                  Text('Dice 2 = ${model.dice2 ?? 'Roll first'}'),
                ],
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Pop back to First Page'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Model extends ChangeNotifier {
  final rnd = Random();
  int? _dice1;
  int? _dice2;

  int? get dice1 => _dice1;
  int? get dice2 => _dice2;

  void roll() {
    _dice1 = rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
    _dice2 = rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, my pages are more complex than what I showed.In first page, when Tabbarviews are initialized, they will send a GET request to get data from database and show the data in view. The second will send a POST request than the website-database may made some changes. When pop, the Tabbarviews need to send the GET request again and then refresh themselves to show the new data. But the parameters of GET request function are still same. So I think provider will not work.

Comment: I think `provider` is just what you need even with that case you described. So, move the GET/POST to the model as methods, store the response in the model itself, and call `notifyListeners` so pages that depend on this response are updated acordingly. And in the POST method call the GET at the end.`

Comment: Maybe you are right, I will make a try.

Comment: @nglshxy did it work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally I used route function "pushNamedAndRemoveUntil" to rebuild the first page. It works. I will update my solution later.

Answer (score 0):

Actually My pages are more complex than the demo. I have a first page with several TabbarViews and each TabbarView also contains several TabbarViews, the numbers of TabbarViews are not fixed.
Finally I selected the route function "pushNamedAndRemoveUntil" to rebuild the first page. Routes of all pages are added in main function and the first page with several TabbarViews is pushed in page stack firstly, then when I visit the second page, it is pushed in page stack secondly. After all operations are fininsed by a POST request in second page, following a Navigator with "pushNamedAndRemoveUntil", the second page in stack would be poped and rebuild whole first page to GET new data from website.
It works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).